# understanding usage of fseek

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("D://test.txt","wb");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }

    typedef struct{
        int a;
        char b;
    }A;

    A x = {12, 'a'}, y = {13, 'b'},z;
    fwrite(&x, sizeof(A), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&y, sizeof(A), 1, fp);

    fseek(fp, sizeof(A), SEEK_SET);

    fread(&z, sizeof(A), 1, fp);
    printf("%d  %c\n", z.a, z.b);
    return 0;
}
```

I intend to write 2 structures to a file. Then I need to position the file pointer to the beginning of the 2nd structure in the file and then perform fread from there to read the 2nd structure into z. The values are not read into z properly. I am not getting where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened the file with "wb", write binary. After writing, you are trying to read the same file. Change the mode from "wb" to "wb+":

```
//fp = fopen("D://test.txt","wb");
fp = fopen("D://test.txt","wb+");
```

to make it work.

Comment: @ajaybidari Great, glad I could help. Would like if you mark my answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Always check every call that could return an error. In your case you'll see that `fread` does not read the data properly. As Carlito said, you should change your mode parameter of `fopen` to `"wb+"` to be able to read from file. And use `perror` instead of just `printf` - so you'll get an informative error messages and it will go to standard error stream, so it could be easy separated from standard output stream if necessary. Also you should break your program flow when error occured, not just print error message.

You should do all these steps automatically, always: check return values; check out, what exactly was happened; change the program flow to handle an error. This is mantra. :)